# Warning: PHPLoc enrichment not enabled or phploc.xml not found in phpDox

Tags: php, jenkins, ant, build.xml, phploc

I generate API documentation for my PHP project with  Jenkins and Ant on project building:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="full-build">
    <property name="pdepend" value="/usr/share/.composer/vendor/bin/pdepend" />
    ...
    <target name="full-build" depends="prepare,static-analysis,phpdox" />
    <target name="prepare" unless="prepare.done" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/api" />
        ...
    </target>
    <target name="clean" unless="clean.done">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/build/api" />
        ...
    </target>
    <target name="static-analysis">
        <parallel threadCount="2">
            <sequential>
                <antcall target="pdepend" />
                <antcall target="phpmd" />
            </sequential>
            <antcall target="lint" />
            <antcall target="phpcpd" />
            <antcall target="phpcs" />
            <antcall target="phploc" />
        </parallel>
    </target>
    <target name="pdepend" unless="pdepend.done" depends="prepare">
        ...
    </target>
    <target name="phpmd" unless="phpmd.done">
        ...
    </target>
    <target name="lint" unless="lint.done">
        ...
    </target>
    <target name="phpcpd" unless="phpcpd.done">
        ...
    </target>
    <target name="phpcs" unless="phpcs.done">
        ...
    </target>
    <target name="phpdox" depends="phploc,phpcs,phpmd" unless="phpdox.done">
        <exec executable="${phpdox}" dir="${basedir}/build" taskname="phpdox">
            <arg value="--file" />
            <arg value="${basedir}/build/phpdox.xml" />
        </exec>
        <property name="phpdox.done" value="true" />
    </target>
    <target name="phploc" unless="phploc.done">
        ...
    </target>
</project>
```

When the build is completed and I open the `index.xhtml` of the API doc, a warning is displayed:

> Warning: PHPLoc enrichment not enabled or phploc.xml not found.

[image]

**Why is this warning displayed and how to solve the issue it caused by?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

phpDox requires a `phploc.xml` file to be generated. Does your target `phploc` generates such a file (param: `--log-xml <filename>`)?

Example target `phploc`:

```
<target name="phploc" unless="phploc.done">
    <exec executable="${phploc}" taskname="phploc">
        <arg value="--count-tests" />
        <arg value="--log-csv" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />
        <arg value="--log-xml" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.xml" />
        <arg path="....." />
    </exec>
    <property name="phploc.done" value="true"/>
</target>
```

If the PHPLOC enricher has not been found or started, the following line should be omitted from the phpDox Ant build script feedback:

```
[phpdox] [06.07.2016 - 16:37:58] Registered enricher 'phploc'
```

Comment: If all else fails, you can always point to the created `phploc.xml` file directly in the `phpdox.xml` config file. You can do this by adding:  `<enrich base="file/dir/of/logs">
    <source type="phploc">
     <file name="phploc.xml" />
    </source>
   </enrich>` inside of the `<generator>` tag of the `phpdox.xml` config file.